# AnimationSet containing ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation does not tween at OS 2.1

Tags: android, animation, tween

I am using an AnimationSet containing ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation. Tweening one image from one size and position to another over a few seconds. It works on a recent device, but the tweening does not occure on an old Xperia device, stuck at OS 2.1. The image just appears in its after-tween state directly. I looked at the reference and the animation classes in question seem to be available since OS 1. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only setting duration on the AnimationSet object.
I tried setting the same duration on the contained scale and translation objects. This made the tweens work.

- I was noticing the same problems using OS 2.2 simulator. The above fixed it in the 2.2 simulator as well.
- I also noticed that adding the animations to the set first and setting the duration later fixes the problem. I used to set duration right after creating the set.